# NGINX & UWSGI - Permission Denied When Trying To Start Server

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am trying to make the raspberry pi 3 into a full stack web developement server, I am folloiwng this guide [here](https://tentacle.net/~prophet/raspberrypi/Raspberry%20Pi%20Full%20Stack%20A%20whirlwind%20tour%20of%20full-stack%20web%20application%20development%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi%202015%20%7BPRG%7D/Raspberry%20Pi%20Full%20Stack%20A%20whirlwind%20tour%20of%20full-stack%20web%20application%20development%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi%20%7BPRG%7D.pdf) and on Step 4.16 page 53, it says to type this command

```
 >uwsgi —ini /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.ini
```

but when I try this command, I get the error below:

```
(venv)pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/lab_app $ uwsgi --ini /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.ini

[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.ini
open("/var/log/uwsgi/lab_app_uwsgi.log"): Permission denied [core/logging.c line 288]
```

I know this is probably related to the groups/users permissions but I'm not exactly sure how I would go about adding or creating a user to have the permissions to start this daemon. I am currently trying to google possible answers but would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Please also find the bellow nginx.conf & uwsgi.ini files located in the directory /var/www/lab_app/, Thanks in advance!

```
**lab_app_nginx.conf**

server {
listen  80;
server_name localhost;
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 75M;
location /static {
        root /var/www/lab_app/;
 }
location / { try_files $uri @labapp; }
location @labapp {
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass unix:/temp/labapp.sock;
 }
}

**lab_app_uwsgi.ini**

uid = www-data
gid = www-data
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/lab_app
#pytyhon module to import
app = hello
module = %(app)
home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)
#sock file's location
socket = /temp/labapp.sock
#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket = 666
#the variable that holds a flask application inside the modue import at line #6
callable = app
#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

Answer (score 2):

This line of the configuration states where the logfile should be stored:

`logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log`

And the process seems to be running as `www-data`:

`uid = www-data`

Therefore I'd check the user/group of `/var/log/uwsgi`, does `www-data` have write permissions there? Does the directory exist?

The `www-data` user probably exists already, it should have been created when you installed nginx. If not you can use `useradd` to add users. Permissions can be changed with `chmod`, ownership can be changed with `chown`.

Answer (score 0):

try to run your server with super-user

```
sudo uwsgi --ini /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.ini
```